# How can several .NET apps on different pc's all copy the same file from a network share simultaneously?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, file-copying

I have an application that multiple people use.  The data the app uses is in the form of a flat file on a network share.  The app copies the file to its local drive before opening it.  The data file is updated every 30 minutes.  The app checks every 5 minutes to see if the has been updated (via comparing timestamps).  If the file has been updated, the app copies the new file down.

With just a few people using the app, there was never an issue with copying the file.  Now they have opened the app for anyone to use.  Overnight it went from just a few people using it to about 50 and this could increase.  Now we are seeing the apps start to copy the file and but it's minutes before it actually begins receiving the file.

I'm using CopyFileEx function in kernel32.dll.

```
Private Declare Auto Function CopyFileEx Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal lpExistingFileName As String, _
      ByVal lpNewFileName As String, ByVal lpProgressRoutine As CopyProgressRoutine, _
      ByVal lpData As IntPtr, ByRef pbCancel As Boolean, _
      ByVal dwCopyFlags As CopyFileFlags) As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)> Boolean

Private Delegate Function CopyProgressRoutine(ByVal TotalFileSize As Long, _
 ByVal TotalBytesTransferred As Long, ByVal StreamSize As Long, ByVal StreamBytesTransferred As Long, _
 ByVal dwStreamNumber As UInteger, ByVal dwCallbackReason As CopyProgressCallbackReason, _
 ByVal hSourceFile As IntPtr, ByVal hDestinationFile As IntPtr, ByVal lpData As IntPtr) As CopyProgressResult

    Success = CopyFileEx(SourcePath, DestPath, New CopyProgressRoutine(AddressOf CopyProgressCallback), IntPtr.Zero, False, If(Overwrite, 0, CopyFileFlags.COPY_FILE_FAIL_IF_EXISTS) Or CopyFileFlags.COPY_FILE_NO_BUFFERING)
```

Does this lock the file while copying?  How can I ensure that each app is not locking the file if so?  Is there a better method to do this?

Comment: Why not use plain File.Copy? Or even better if you want full control, two streams, one to read and other to write? In the second case you can open the streams with read share to ensure multiple access.

Comment: Better network card and disks on server. Then redesign your app to use a server instead of copying data locally. Why don't you just readonly open remote file? . (in the middle you might want to split server file in smaller parts, no need to re download  what didn't change).

Comment: I was told File.Copy locked the source file and that using streams was extremely slow for copying files, especially across a WAN.  I used CopyFileEx because I could omit the COPY_FILE_OPEN_SOURCE_FOR_WRITE flag.

Comment: I don't control the data file. That comes from some other corporate entity. I don't have control over the server either.

Comment: The solution would be to use the Volume Shadow Copy Service, which allows read and write while other process has it locked. Or create a `FileStream` to read the file and another one that will `Read` the stream and write it out...

Comment: add a new server that copies the file to a db or webserver, and use let all the clients copy from there?

Comment: The issue is not really a locking issue.  The problem is that updating cannot be performed while the file is being read by other people.  It would be better to store the file in a database which is shared like SQL server and then have the app query the database for the file.